# Next / Previous button with <a> build with $_GET

Tags: php, html

I have an html webpage with a next and previous button. The url for the button is different for each page you are already on. The code for the next page is like this

```
<a href='<?=$_GET['1'];?>/<?=$_GET['2'];?>/<?=$_GET['3']+1;?>'>Next</a>    
<a class=href='<?=$_GET['1'];?>/<?=$_GET['2']/<?=$_GET['3']-1;?>;?>'> Previous</a>
```

the url is like `www.website.com/text1/text2/number`

```
text1 is what u get with GET['1'] 

text2 is what u get with GET['2]

You get the number with GET['3']
```

**It is working perfectly in all browsers except in Internet Explorer**. 
I have already
    `meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"` in my header

But in IE when you hit the button (no matter wich one) it will make something like `www.website.com/text1/text1/text2/text2/number`

Comment: sounds like a relative url problem - have you tried just placing a leading slash in the links, eg: `<a href='/<?=$_GET['1'];?>...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting full link of your desired webpage address in href.

For example

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/<?=$_GET['1'];?>/<?=$_GET['2'];?>/<?=($_GET['3']-1);?>"> Previous</a>
```

Comment: @dray this will give an error if the third parameter i.e. `$_GET['3']` is not an integer.

Comment: he didn't have a problem in the php part, my code was just an example. His problem was with the href.

Answer (score 0):

maybe u ment that? here you calculate the second argument

```
<a class='' href='<?=$_GET['1'];?>/<?=(($_GET['2']/$_GET['3'])-1);?>'> Previous</a>
```

or that? here you link to several subdirectories

```
<a class='' href='<?=$_GET['1'];?>/<?=$_GET['2'];?>/<?=($_GET['3']-1);?>'> Previous</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the url in the anchor tag, wouldn't it be easier if ,

```
$p1 = $_GET['1'];
$p2 = $_GET['2'];
$p3 = intval($_GET['3']);
$pPrev = intval($p3 - 1);
$pNext = intval($p3 + 1);

$prevUrl = $p1 . "/" . $p2 . "/" . $pPrev;
$nextUrl = $p1 . "/" . $p2 . "/" . $pNext;
<a href='<?php echo $nextUrl; ?>'>Next</a>    
<a href='<?php echo $prevUrl; ?>'> Previous</a>
```

It should resolve the error you are getting in parsing the third parameter in the url.